# Retrieve data from real time firebase in useEffect return undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, use-effect

I tried to implement the followers/following function and it succeeds but, I have a problem retrieving followers and following lists from real-time firebase.

When the user presses on another username followers/following, it sends the uid of the pressed user to this class, then by using the uid followers' list is retrieved and displayed.

The uid is correct at the beginning of the class, but the followers' list returns `undefined` and sometimes it returns a list on the second save(when I press Ctrl+s).

```js
export default function showFollowers({
    navigation,
    route
}) {

    const [followerslist, setFollowersList] = useState();
    const [uid, setuid] = useState(route.params.uid);
    const [usersList, setUsersList] = useState([]);
    const followersl = [];
    // ---snip---
}
```

HERE, the followers list returned undefined.

```js
useEffect(
    () => {
        const usersRef1 = firebase.database()
            .ref('users/' + uid)
            .child("followers");
        usersRef1.on('value', async (snapshot) => {
            const users1 = snapshot.val();
            //const followersl= [];
            for (let id in users1) {
                followersl.push(users1[id]);
            }
            await setFollowersList(followersl)
            console.log(followerslist) // undefined
            console.log(uid) // correct
        });
    },
    []
);
```

// Calling second to return info of each follower [profile image,username,name] to be displayed as flat list.

```js
second;

const second = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < followerslist.length; i++) {
        getInfo(followerslist[i]);
    }
}

const getInfo = (element) => {
    const usersRef = firebase.database()
        .ref('users')
        .orderByChild('usernameLC')
        .equalTo(element.toString().toLowerCase());

    usersRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
        const users = snapshot.val();


        for (let id in users) {
            usersList.push(users[id]);
        }

        setUsersList(usersList);
    });

}
```

Comment: Please use a JS formatter to format the code and then paste it. Right now, it's very hard to read the code. Suggested formatter- https://beautifier.io/

Comment: I did, but there is no change @ShivamSingla

Comment: `it sends the uid of the pressed user to this class`. Which class is being referred to?

Comment: Show followers @ShivamSingla

Comment: I am no expert with react hooks, but from [this](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.techiediaries.com/amp/react-usestate-hook-update-array/), it seems you need to pass initial empty array in `useState([])`, and update like this- `setFollowersList(() => followersl)`

Comment: Yes, it's empty. it's supposed to be retrieved by using the uid. @ShivamSingla

Comment: Is the update correct? Also, could please log `users1`?